# 128 barcode print spaces

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers

I am trying to print a 128 barcode on a zebra zm400 label printer the barcode is 23 characters long using the zebra programming language  The barcode contains a single space however every time I send the barcode to the printer it adds 2 extra spaces.  E.g.  ABC3 1345678998765432001 two spaces are added to the space between 3 and 1.  Even if I print a barcode with no spaces then two spaces are added at the end before the last e.g. 001 becomes 00  1.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I am using

^XA ^LH30,20 ^SZ2 ^MD15 ^LT0 ^MFN,N ^JZY ^PMN ^JMA ^LRY
^PW750
^BY2
^BCN,180,Y,N,N,
^FDACV8 512345678901234001^FS
^MUd
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

No matter what I try I the printer always inserts two spaces.  I have tried using ^FH and the _20 character for a space but this still inserts two spaces.

Comment: Please show your code that generates & sends the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at [Your Label](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&zpl=%5EXA%20%5ELH30%2C20%20%5ESZ2%20%5EMD15%20%5ELT0%20%5EMFN%2CN%20%5EJZY%20%5EPMN%20%5EJMA%20%5ELRY%0A%5EPW750%0A%5EBY2%0A%5EBCN%2C180%2CY%2CN%2CN%2C%0A%5EFH%5EFDACV8%20512345678901234001%5EFS%0A%5EMUd%0A%5EPQ1%2C0%2C1%2CY%5EXZ) it looks like it should be mapping a single space, have you tried dropping the ZPL directly into the printer via the Web interface and seeing if you still get 2 spaces? could the issue come from how you are sending the file?

Comment: Yep that was it I was testing the label by outputting to notepad first then printing.  However when I sent the code directly via the code it printed fine thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Code 128 Barcode FAQ at ID Automation (http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/code-128/) I found that the space character uses ASCII 194/C2 instead of 20. Try the ^FH and C2.

```
...
^FH^FDACV8_C2512345678901234001^FS
...
```